# How to display Arabic notations in left-to-right direction in QLineEdit/QLabel etc.?

Tags: qt, arabic, text-alignment, qlineedit, qlabel

In Qt's implementation **arabic notation** is shown in **right-to-left** direction, thus any strings that contain arabic notations will be right-aligned.

But what my application wants to do is showing all texts in **left-to-right** direction, whether it contains arabic notations or not. And all texts are left-aligned.

An example is shown below:

- This is ***what I want to implement***

  [image: what I want to implement]
- This is how **`QLineEdit`** displays texts containing arabic notations in its default way

  [image: arabic notation in QLineEdit]
- This is how **`QLabel`** does it

  [image: arabic notation in QLabel]

## EDIT:

Paste the test string here. ە抠门哥ە(

## EDIT:

Providing an alternate solution.

Finally I can achieve my goal roughly by using `QTextEdit` which has a `QTextDocument`. The following code snippet shows how I did it. But I have no idea how Qt deals with text direction from a global perspective, so I can't achieve my goal with `QLabel` etc... **It would be great if someone can give some detailed information about Qt's text engine.**

```
QTextDocument *doc = ui->textEdit->document();
QTextOption textOption = doc->defaultTextOption();
textOption.setTextDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
doc->setDefaultTextOption(textOption);
ui->textEdit->setDocument(doc);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicode provides **Directional Formatting Characters**,and Qt supports it well.

Thus,for **`QLabel`** and **`QLineEdit`** etc. we can insert a **`LRM`** control character
 ,which is define in **Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm**, at the beginning of a **RightToLeft** string to make the string **left-alignment**.For more information about **Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm**,click [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/).

```
QString(QChar(0x200E))+strText;
```

And for **`QTextEdit`** etc. which has a **`QTextDocument`** we can make **RightToLeft** string **left-alignment** by setting **`QTextDocment`**'s `textDirection` to **`Qt::LeftToRight`**.

ps:
**`QString`** has a **`isRightToLeft`** member function to decide whether the string is **RightToLeft** or not. For example,a string that begins with a notation from **Right-to-left** writting language is **RightToLeft**.

I answered [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615175/how-to-make-right-to-left-language-eg-arabic-characters-behave-like-left-to-ri/27653970#27653970),which maybe helpful for finding your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt documentation about `setLayoutDirection` you can read :

> This method no longer affects text layout direction since Qt 4.7.

So you can not use this method. For `QLineEdit` you can send a `Qt::Key_Direction_L` keyboard event to the line edit to make it left to right event if the characters are Arabic or Persian :

```
QKeyEvent event(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Direction_L, 0);
qApp->sendEvent(ui->lineEdit, &event);
```

Comment: Thanks.I will try it.But I think it has limitations,it will be great if there is a more common way to solve the problem.