# How to make right-to-left language (eg.Arabic) characters behave like left-to-right languages do in qt?

Tags: qt, arabic, right-to-left, qtextedit, left-to-right

**`Qt`** provides a powerful adaptive way to deal with **`left-to-right`** languages and **`right-to-left`** languages texts.But I encounter my problems dealing with my goals.

---

*Picture No.1 What I want to get*
[image: image no.1]

---

*Picture No.2 What I got when **paste** to my `QTextEdit` based widget what picture no.1 shows*
[image: image no.2]

---

*Picture No.3 What I got when I set text-direction to left-to-right as shown below:*

```
QTextDocument *doc = ui->textEdit->document();
QTextOption textOption = doc->defaultTextOption();
textOption.setTextDirection(Qt::LeftToRight);
doc->setDefaultTextOption(textOption);
ui->textEdit->setDocument(doc);
```

[image: image no.3]

```
Making it left-to-right aligned is not that hard,
but the result differs from what picture no.1 shows.
```

---

*Picture No.4 What I got when I try appending texts to the terminal*
[image: image no.4]

---

```
What I want to achieve is the fact that it shows like picture no.1 does,

and key-strikes make texts appended to the terminal
 
when the existting texts is terminated by a Arabic notation.

In a word,all I want is that it behave like left-to-right languages do

whether it contains right-to-left language characters or not.
```

Comment: If QT supports Unicode completely, you can try the special character called left to right embedding: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-controls

Comment: Have you tried to send a `Qt::Key_Direction_L` keyboard event to your widget to see if it helps. Like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517981/how-to-display-arabic-notations-in-left-to-right-direction-in-qlineedit-qlabel-e/27518579#27518579

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode provides **`Directional Formatting Characters`**,and **`Qt`** supports it well.The idea comes from @VahidN.My problem is solved partly via this way,now it display **bidirection string** properly.

```
QString(QChar(0x200E))+strText; //LRM
QString(QChar(0x202D)) + strText + QString(QChar(0x202C)); //LRO...PDF
```

Before this question I answered [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517981/how-to-display-arabic-notations-in-left-to-right-direction-in-qlineedit-qlabel-e/27653861#27653861),which maybe helpful for finding your own solution.